# Program that seeks out relevant files, then downloads, tags, and organizes them into folders

Tags: file-management, download-manager

I want a program that works in this fashion:

1. I give the program criteria for the types of files I want *(example: file type, title, or even all files within a certain website)*
2. It searches the websites I tell it to look through and downloads all files meeting that criteria *(example: I could say that I want to download all files of type .jpg from a website that have the word "cat" in the title. The program would download all relevant files and I would not have to point it to each link individually, saving me time)*
3. It organizes the files it downloads into certain folders also based on criteria that I define *(Say I had folders named "calico", "black", and "orange" and I told the program to organize the files based on what was in the title of the images downloaded. Therefore a .jpg image named calicocat.jpg would go into the calico folder)*
4. It assigns relevant tags to each file it downloads, "relevant" tags are also defined by me
5. I can then search this database of files I have collected by title, or by any of the tags the files have been assigned

Comment: Your question is **very difficult** to read. Take a moment to edit the question into a legible format and make sure [it contains sufficient information](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)

Comment: You could do what you want using keepvid.com and bookmarking. A software is never ever can be able to know what is an *appropriate* folder.

Comment: Raystafarian, I think you are exaggerating when you say very difficult, my English was clear. However, I do think that this nice little list is a more convenient format for people to read. Let me know if it is still unclear to you. I certainly hope I will find a response relevant to what I am looking for now.

Comment: cagirici, thank you for your response. I will look into this and update my post accordingly if this is what I am looking for.

Comment: cagirici, I appreciate your suggestion, but that is not exactly what I am looking for. What do you mean when you say software can never know what folder is appropriate?

Comment: @arelevantuser would you provide some examples of criteria? For example, would you need natural language processing or just regular expressions? Would each be a small program?

Comment: Sure. I did describe three different types of criteria, so I'll go into what I mean for each.

Comment: As for the criteria for what files should be downloaded, I was thinking along the lines of file type, title, or even all files within a certain website. Actually, now that I think of it, these criteria would be applicable for every stage of the program that I describe. As long as the program can discriminate based on those simple qualities of the file, that will be fine for me.

Comment: Perhaps as an example, I could say that I want to download all files of type .jpg from a website that have the word "cat" in the title. The program would download all relevant files and I would not have to point it to each link individually, saving me time. Then the program would organize the files into my folders also based on criteria. Say I had folders named "calico", "black", and "orange" and I told the program to organize the files based on what was in the title of the images downloaded. Therefore a .jpg image named calicocat.jpg would go into the calico folder. Make sense?

Comment: Oh, and if there are a few different small programs that I could use to achieve the same effect, I would be fine with that.